# After upgrade to 14.10 and Gnome 3.14.1 keyboard layout is not switching

Tags: gnome, upgrade, keyboard-layout, 14.10

After upgrade to 14.10 and Gnome 3.14.1 I've an issue with switching keyboard layout from English to Russian, it's in the list of the languages' indicator, indicator language is OK switching but input always English. I still can switch layout using command: "setxkbmap ru" or "setxkbmap us"
How I've to fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this work with gnome 3.12, the gnome desktop release that officialy came with ubuntu 14.10?

Comment: @xangua Yes it works! But 3.14.1 is preferable for me.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: It is fixed now ... see below.

This problem has been reported as a bug in Ubuntu GNOME:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1385844

It looks like a cause of the problem has been found. Hopefully, developers will prepare a fix soon. I will update this answer when something changes.

UPDATE 2014/11/12:

In mentioned bug reported you can find a link to package prepared by one of the users, here is the link as well: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1385844/+attachment/4259037/+files/gnome-settings-daemon_3.14.0-1ubuntu1~utopic1_amd64.deb

It fixes the problem for me but beware ... Ubuntu will try to update this package back to official with the same version, so don't let it do it.

UPDATE 2014/12/04:

It is fixed with new version 3.14.2-0ubuntu1~utopic1 of gnome-settings-daemon from GNOME Team's Staging PPA.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I am unable to post a comment to answers due to too few reputation points. But my "comment" is legit and needed since it may shed light on how to avoid Ubuntu to update the patch to its original version.

So I ask if it might help using 'aptitude' to forbid the Ubuntu's official version? and if so, how it is done?

Thank you.

Comment: It would be done like this. First install Synaptic Package Manager (synaptic) from the Ubuntu Software Center and then use the *Force Version* and *Lock Version* features of Synaptic to select the package version that you want, and prevent the Update Manager from updating the package version that you want to keep. You can have both Synaptic and the Ubuntu Software Center installed at the same time. These are nice features to have when an update to the Linux kernel starts doing what it's not supposed to do, and you need to roll back to the previous version of the kernel.